icarus verilog under windows gives error. Building from source instructions are missing
We tried to run icarus verilog for students on windows. For some students it seems to work
For others, we get the following error on Windows 11 Home for example:
iverilog -o test.exe test.sv

Cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of windows

Not sure why, I have compiled 32-bit mingw code before, but I don't understand the DLL situation on every student machine.
In desperation, we tried to build from source:

Install msys2
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc autoconf gperf make bison flex
Instructions say to read mingw.txt which does not exist.

I tried just running autoconf but that didn't seem to work, at least there is no Makefile built.
So first, is there any way to get the 32-bit version working, what would make some students' computers more hostile to 32-bit apps than others?
Second, what is the procedure to build the code?
./autoconf  # ???
./autoconf configure.ac   # ???


The error message "Cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of windows" usually means you are trying to start a 16 bit program but Windows 64 bit can not execute 16 bit programs.
